# converting rdms like instagram to firebase nosql

Tags: firebase, database-design, nosql, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I am planning to develop production ready hybrid **ionic3** mobile application similar to **instagram** using firebase. I chose **firestore** nosql for storing data and querying.

I have experience designing schema in RDMS ( ignore second green colored user table ). But I am struggling to design **NoSql** schema for my application.
Below I added RDMS schema that I want to convert it to nosql.
[image: rdms table schema]

**There are several queries I want to make efficiently.**

1. Show list of latest photos in homepage for guest session.
2. Show list of followers photos followed by the user in homepage.
3. List photos tagged by "tag"

**Simple Sql query for above list**

1. `Select * from photo LIMIT=50`

How should I approach to convert **photo** and **user** table to firestore NoSql OR NoSql in order to query efficiently?

Comment: While interesting, I think this question is just too broad as it stands.

Comment: @Andrew what I want is to show photos based on users following list

Comment: Does that NoSql have an `ORDER BY` clause in the language (for item 1)?  `UNION` (for item 2)?  `JOIN` (for item 3)?  If not, then why are you moving _away from_ an RDMS?

Comment: @RickJames because firebase only supports nosql. And I want to use it as a backend for my mobile app. It has `order by`, no `joins` and `unions`

Comment: The problem is I can not make `joins` and `nested queries` like sql. Because firebase is evolving, and they plan to support clauses, like `in`.

Comment: I don't understand.  You want "query efficiency", yet you are moving _to_ a less powerful platform?

Comment: it has many benefits, auto scaling, real time, authentication, monitoring apps, drawback is `less clauses`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal:

One Collection named `photos`

with `photo` documents that have:

- an auto-generated Id
- a `creation` field holding a date (i.e. a timestamp)
- the extra fields like description, url/path, etc.
- a `tags` field as an object with key-value pairs like `{black: true, cats: true}`, see this help doc for the rationale: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays. The HTML code below shows how to use/query it
- a sub-collection of `comments`

One Collection named `users`

with `user` documents that have:

- the Id of the user (i.e. `uid` from the authentication)
- a `followedUsers` object holding the ids of the users followed by the current user `{userId1: true, userId2: true}`
- a `followedPhotosId` object holding the ids of the photos followed by the current user `{9HzWzyXmcnBDuhTZKoQw: true, fO0OvzJs9M8p9N0jufte: true}`
- a `followedPhotos` sub-collection holding the details of the followed photos

The following HTML page shows how to execute the queries you list in your post, as well as some queries reading and writing data: these latest queries should be used in several Cloud Functions dedicated to keeping the `followedPhotosId` objects and `followedPhotos` Collections in synch when a user follows a new other user and/or when a user (followed by one or more users) adds or deletes a photo.

```
<html>

<head>

<!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxx"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var firestoredb = firebase.firestore();


  firestoredb.collection("photos").orderBy("creation", "desc")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        console.log("YOUR QUERY #1");
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });


  firestoredb.collection("users").doc("user1").collection("followedPhotos")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        console.log("YOUR QUERY #2");
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });


  firestoredb.collection("photos")
    .where('tags.cats', '==', true) //You should create a photo with a "cats" tag
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        console.log("YOUR QUERY #3");
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });




  firestoredb.collection("photos").orderBy("creation", "desc").limit(50)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        console.log("YOUR QUERY #4, i.e; Select * from photo LIMIT=50");
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });

  firestoredb.collection("users")
   .where('followedUsers.user2', '==', true)
   .get()
   .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      console.log("Get all the users who follows user2. To use in the Cloud Function");
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });


   firestoredb.collection("users")
    .where('followedPhotosId.9HzWzyXmcnBDuhTZKoQw', '==', true)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        console.log("Get all the users who follow photo with Id 9HzWzyXmcnBDuhTZKoQw. To use in the Cloud Function");
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });


    firestoredb.collection("users").doc("user1").get().then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Update the followedPhotosId object for user1 after a user she/he follows has added a photo with id abcdefghijklmn. To use in the Cloud Function");
          var followedPhotosId = doc.data().followedPhotosId;;
          Object.assign(followedPhotosId, {abcdefghijklmn: true});
      firestoredb.collection("users").doc("user1").set({followedPhotosId: followedPhotosId});
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });




</script>


<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) to Firestore's Guide in designing your data model. Additionally, you need to think in how information would be accessed, so your queries are as flat as possible (as there shouldn't be joins in NoSQL).

For example, if you need a screen that shows user's information with his/her photo, create a collection named **User**, and add a subcollection **Photo** to it. If you need a list of user photos, then create a separate collection of **Photo**.

I recommend to follow [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) for your **related data**, but be careful, as it could be hard to maintain.

As a last recommendation (and personal opinion), you need to throw away your SQL knowledge and stop thinking in how your data is related, and then think in how your information can be accessed in a way that fits your application, and take advantage of [Firestore indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview).

Comment: can you add illustration for your example?